# enable tracing jgroup on websphere 8.5.5

Tags: websphere, trace, jgroups

I need to enable jgroup tracing on WebSphere 8.5.5, but can't find and option for:

org.jgroups.protocols.*

in Logging and tracing > server8 > Change log detail levels

Thank you

edabxv

Comment: You can still set the trace string manually in the trace string window, for example `*=info: org.jgroups.protocols.*=all`.

Comment: Thanks Daniel I did, but nothing is tracing

Comment: Have you enabled tracing over all and you are looking in the correct file?

Is `org.jgroups.protocols` logging using JUL? The trace parameters won't work for other logging frameworks such as log4j or Apache commons logging unless they in their turn use JUL for logging.

Comment: I don't know what it is using, just know that in previous versions of websphere all I had to do is to add it to WebSphere:

Application servers > server8 > server8 > Change log detail levels
*=info: org.jgroups.protocols.*=all

Comment: And just to check, you are looking in the correct log file?

Comment: yes, it always was in SystemOut

Comment: No, tracing ends up in trace.log.